Adding a class to dplyr mutate .data argument gives Error in `vec_data()`: ! `x` must be a vector, not a <data.frame/myclass> object
After appending a new class to a data frame, I can no longer run dplyr functions on the data frame. Two examples here. Initially I can apply dplyr::mutate and dplyr::filter with no problems.
## Create df
df <- data.frame("value" = 1:3)
class(df)

[1] "data.frame"

## Apply mutate or filter
dplyr::mutate(df, value_new = value^2)
dplyr::filter(df, value < 3)

However after adding a class:
## Add a class
class(df) <- append(class(df), "myclass")
class(df)

[1] "data.frame" "myclass" 

## Apply mutate or filter
dplyr::mutate(df, value_new = value^2)
dplyr::filter(df, value < 2)

Returns the following errors:
Error in `vec_data()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <data.frame/myclass> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Error in `vec_slice()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <data.frame/myclass> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

As I understand, appending a new class to an object whcih already has a class, should not impact how the object is treated when other S3 methods are applied to it, because there is a hierarchical structure (inheritence: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-inheritance). However, I a getting a little out of my depth.
I would like to add a new class because I am developing an R package, and I want to assign some new classes to some objects as part of this. I think explaining/understanding the problem above should be sufficient to be able to do this, but I can provide more details about the new S3 generic I am attempting to create if neccesary.
Many thanks

You should put your custom class before the existing ones, not after. Try class(df) <- c("myclass", class(df)) and it should work

You are correct, thank you! Are you able to explain why? This seems counter to what is in the Hadley advanced R book "If a method is not found for the class in the first element of the vector, R looks for a method for the second class (and so on)". By putting my class first, this means dplyr::mutate will look at the first element ("myclass"), there is no method mutate for this, then move onto second element ("data.frame"), and successfully find the method? Having the new class as the second element, I would expectmutate would look at the first class ("data.frame") and then use this?

Your understanding is generally correct. But vctrs, which dplyr relies on, is much more picky. See the technical limitations in ?vctrs::obj_check_vector: "Subclasses of data.frame that append their class to the back of the "class" attribute are not treated as vectors. If you inherit from an S3 class, always prepend your class to the front of the "class" attribute for correct dispatch. This matches our general principle of allowing subclasses but not mixins."

Aha, I see, thank you both, much appreciated.
